# MYSQL:Connect to both localhost & host.docker.internal

Tags: mysql, docker, sequelize.js

I have to connect to both localhost as well as docker.

```
const db = new Sequelize({
  host : 'host.docker.internal'| process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  dialect: 'mysql'
})
```

In the following code , when I run
`node app.js` it runs on the machine. But when I run `docker run -p 3000:3000 [imagehash]` it throws the following error

`ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`

and when I run

```
const db = new Sequelize({
  host : 'host.docker.internal',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  dialect: 'mysql'
})
```

it runs perfectly on `docker run -p 3000:3000 [imagehash]`

How to run on both perfectly

NOTE : process.env.DB_HOST = localhost

Answer (score 0):

When you construct the database connection information, check the environment variable *first*.  It's often useful to set the fallback value to what you'd want this to be in your everyday development environment.

```js
const db = new Sequelize({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
  ...
});
```

Then when you do run it in Docker, you need to provide the value of that environment variable.

```sh
# If the database isn't in a container
docker run -e DB_HOST=host.docker.internal -p 3000:3000 myapp
```

```yaml
# If the database is in a container; typical Compose setup
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db # matching the name of the service below
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      mysql_data: /var/lib/mysql/data
volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you try to connect to a mysql db who run on the host,
To make it work just add `--network host` argument to your run command.
[related documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers)

After that, the best pratice is to [create a mysql db inside container](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker) and [link it with your application](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#connect-with-the-linking-system)